# Typescript combined interfaces, access specific prop, construct new type by values of specific prop

Tags: typescript

I've two interfaces for `useReducer` actions in React.

They are combined to a new type, called `Actions`.

```js
interface AddToCart {
  type: "addToCart"
  book: Book
}

interface RemoveFromCart {
  type: "removeFromCart"
  book: Book
}

type Actions = AddToCart | RemoveFromCart
```

What I need is a new type, combining all the `string` values of `type` property: `type ActionTypes = "addToCart" | "removeFromCart"`.

How to generate `ActionTypes` with `Actions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
type ActionTypes = AddToCart['type'] | RemoveFromCart['type']
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=62&pln=23&pc=1#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).

To derive from `Actions`:

```
type ActionTypes = Actions['type']
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's close but not exactly I was asking for. It's not generated by `Actions`. In real application I've much more interfaces and I only want to maintain `Actions`.

Comment: It's even more straightforward to derive from `Actions` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
interface Action{
  type:string
}

interface AddToCart extends Action {
  type: "addToCart"
  book: Book
}

interface RemoveFromCart extends Action{
  type: "removeFromCart"
  book: Book
}

type Actions = AddToCart | RemoveFromCart;
type ActionTypes = Actions["type"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all value of `sring` and ignore name (`type`) you can try this:

Based on [this](https://www.piotrl.net/typescript-condition-subset-types/) you can apply a condition for each key. Depending on the result, we set the name as the type or we put never, which is our flag for keys that we don’t want to see in the new type:

```
type FilterFlags<Base, Condition> = {
    [Key in keyof Base]: 
        Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
};
```

Now get the key that passed your validation:

```
type AllowedNames<Base, Condition> =
        FilterFlags<Base, Condition>[keyof Base]
```

And Now use `Pick`, which iterates over provided key names and extracts the associated type to the new object:

```
type SubType<Base, Condition> = 
        Pick<Base, AllowedNames<Base, Condition>>

type ActionTypes1 = SubType<Actions, string>; //"addToCart" | "removeFromCart"
```

But if you care about the name (say `type`) simply use:

```
type ActionTypes = Actions["type"];
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=6&pln=28&pc=18#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHt0GsDeBfAKANElkRQEEATKgFXQGE4oxkcDlkwBPABwgBcyAERwa9Ji2EdkAI0xYhGbAULFw0eEmQAlCAFt0ANwgAxKOn2TW7Tj35DhUA8bMWrzMNM7zsShapEBPaUCGDA6CAAzsgAvMjUdIyeyAA%20ui4m5pbWRCHIpsAANqSmRXAA5lEAPKhwURAANMgMkVTA4ZEAfHFsMpwA2gDSENzIoMhYo%20gwaPUQALpC-ZyrdQ3DowvIEAAekCBUMa2HHREgyAD8yCNjQiAQJlCqANx5fJRFRegA7hBUADk4PoIDV1k0Wm0zt04itVgViqVylVavNmid2p0QF0BlNuDM5g0FkF8gBlACusloH1RDXRUKxPXicPhqwACsAEFhaRCKF9fv8gSCwWjIadGV13vwEmFztT%20FEAIy9ClUmkUWWRKLNKJgKCgCpdF7IIhAA)